# Open Quick Launch links in new window programmatically

Tags: quick-launch

I have saved a team site solution in the gallery which lets the user create subsites. Now the user would like to open some quicklaunch links in a new window when the new subsite is created.

How can I open a library/list in a new window programmatically, since the saved template does not retain the options that I have specified before I saved it?

Edit:
here is my code so far but is not working:

```
 public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.WebProvisioned(properties);

        SPNavigationNodeCollection leftNav = properties.Web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
        SPNavigationNode node = leftNav.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl("/Shared Documents");
        node.Properties["Target"] = "_blank";
        node.Update();
        properties.Web.Update();

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can follow this [link](http://www.uccorner.com/32/sharepoint/sharepoint-open-links-in-new-window/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might have found solution for this,  but this is what i would have done to achieve this.

Create a jQuery script to update the links target [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827637/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-a-new-window)

Add reference to this js onto home page of the sub site,  create a new template and start creating new sites based on this template.

I hope this will help someone in future