# Open Quick Launch link in new window (CSOM)

Tags: client-object-model, publishing, quick-launch

How to add a link opening in a new window/tab to the quick launch menu using CSOM?

There is some discussion about the server-side [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94924/open-quick-launch-links-in-new-window-programmatically) and [here](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/04/managing-quick-launch-current.html) but they are dealing with the [Properties collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode.properties.aspx) of [SPNavigationNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode(v=office.15).aspx). Those properties do not seem to be present in the client-side [NavigationNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigationnode_members(v=office.15).aspx) and jQuery is not an option.

[image: opening-quick-launch-navigation-link-in-new-window]
`_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`